# Trying to implement a simple loader for 32 bit elf files which do not contain any glibc API

Tags: c, operating-system

While running the program it runs fine for a program which calculates fibonacci number
however it is showing segmentation fault if I use an even simpler code for calculation of sum of numbers in an array .
This is my makefile(in case compilation is not done correctly)

```
all:
    gcc  -g -m32 -no-pie -nostdlib -o fib fib.c
    gcc  -g -m32 -no-pie -nostdlib -o sum sum.c
    gcc  -g -m32 -o loader loader.c
clean:
    -@rm -f fib loader sum
```

Take a look at my test cases

```
int fib(int n) {
  if(n<2) return n;
  else return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
}

int _start() {
    int val = fib(40);
    return val;
}
```

```
#define SIZE 1024
int __attribute__((aligned(4096))) A[SIZE] = {0};
int sum = 0;
int _start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        A[i] = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        sum += A[i];
    return sum;
}
```

my code

```
void load_and_run_elf(char **exe)
{
    char *filename = exe[1];
    printf("file name : %s\n", filename);
    fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    printf("fd : %d\n", fd);
    off_t size = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (size < 0)
    {
        printf("error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    ehdr = (Elf32_Ehdr *)malloc(sizeof(Elf32_Ehdr));
    if (ehdr == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR : memory not allocated to ehdr\n");
    }
    read(fd, ehdr, sizeof(Elf32_Ehdr));
    if (check_elf_header() != 1)
    {
        printf("error invalid format\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    check_elf_class();
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    phdr = (Elf32_Phdr *)malloc(sizeof(Elf32_Phdr) * ehdr->e_phnum);
    lseek(fd, ehdr->e_phoff, SEEK_SET);
    read(fd, phdr, ehdr->e_phnum * sizeof(Elf32_Phdr));
    int index;
    for (int i = 0; i < ehdr->e_phnum; i++)
    {
        lseek(fd, ehdr->e_phoff + i * sizeof(Elf32_Phdr), SEEK_SET);
        read(fd, phdr, sizeof(Elf32_Phdr));
        if ((phdr[i].p_type == PT_LOAD) &&
            (ehdr->e_entry >= phdr[i].p_vaddr) &&
            (ehdr->e_entry <= (phdr[i].p_vaddr + phdr[i].p_memsz)))
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
        lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    }
    void *virtual_memory = mmap(NULL, phdr[index].p_memsz, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, 0, 0);
    if (virtual_memory == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("ERROR : memory not mapped\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    lseek(fd, phdr[index].p_offset, SEEK_SET);
    read(fd, virtual_memory, phdr[index].p_memsz);
    printf("reached line 65\n");
    void *virtual_memory_copy = virtual_memory;
    virtual_memory_copy = (void *)((uint8_t *)virtual_memory_copy + ehdr->e_entry - phdr->p_vaddr);
    printf("reached line 69\n");
    int (*function)() = (int (*)())virtual_memory_copy; // _start();
    printf("%p\n",function);
    int result = function();
    printf("131\n");
    printf("entry point : %p\n", virtual_memory_copy);
    if (munmap(virtual_memory, phdr[index].p_memsz) != 0)
    {
        printf("error memory not unmaped\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("User _start return value = %d\n", result);
}
```

When my code tries to load and run sum.c it gives segmentation fault but it runs ./fib just fine
but when I try to run ./sum

```bash
file name : ./sum
fd : 3
reached line 65
reached line 69
0xf7eca000
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

this is the output of ( relevent part of output )gdb when I debug my code while it tries to run ./sum(elf of sum.c)

```bash
96      for (int i = 0; i < ehdr->e_phnum; i++)
(gdb) next
98          lseek(fd, ehdr->e_phoff + i * sizeof(Elf32_Phdr), SEEK_SET);
(gdb) next
99          read(fd, phdr, sizeof(Elf32_Phdr));
(gdb) next
100         if ((phdr[i].p_type == PT_LOAD) &&
(gdb) next
101             (ehdr->e_entry >= phdr[i].p_vaddr) &&
(gdb) next
100         if ((phdr[i].p_type == PT_LOAD) &&
(gdb) next
102             (ehdr->e_entry <= (phdr[i].p_vaddr + phdr[i].p_memsz)))
(gdb) next
101             (ehdr->e_entry >= phdr[i].p_vaddr) &&
(gdb) next
104             index = i;
(gdb) next
105             break;
(gdb) prit ehdr
Undefined command: "prit".  Try "help".
(gdb) print ehdr
$3 = (Elf32_Ehdr *) 0x5655a5b0
(gdb) print phdr
$4 = (Elf32_Phdr *) 0x5655a5f0
(gdb) print *ehdr
$5 = {e_ident = "\177ELF\001\001\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000", e_type = 2, e_machine = 3, e_version = 1, e_entry = 134516736, e_phoff = 52, e_shoff = 13500, e_flags = 0, e_ehsize = 52, 
  e_phentsize = 32, e_phnum = 7, e_shentsize = 40, e_shnum = 17, e_shstrndx = 16}
(gdb) print *phdr
$6 = {p_type = 1, p_offset = 4096, p_vaddr = 134516736, p_paddr = 134516736, p_filesz = 110, p_memsz = 110, p_flags = 5, p_align = 4096}
(gdb) next
109     void *virtual_memory = mmap(NULL, phdr[index].p_memsz, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, 0, 0);
(gdb) next
110     if (virtual_memory == MAP_FAILED)
(gdb) next
115     lseek(fd, phdr[index].p_offset, SEEK_SET);
(gdb) next
116     read(fd, virtual_memory, phdr[index].p_memsz);
(gdb) next
117     printf("reached line 65\n");
(gdb) print phdr[index].p_memsz
$7 = 110
(gdb) prit sizeof(virtual_memory)
Undefined command: "prit".  Try "help".
(gdb) print sizeof(virtual_memory)
$8 = 4
(gdb) next
reached line 65
118     void *virtual_memory_copy = virtual_memory;
(gdb) next
119     virtual_memory_copy = (void *)((uint8_t *)virtual_memory_copy + ehdr->e_entry - phdr->p_vaddr);
(gdb) print virtual_memory-virtual_memory_copy
$9 = 0
(gdb) next
120     printf("reached line 69\n");
(gdb) next
reached line 69
121     int (*function)() = (int (*)())virtual_memory_copy; // _start();
(gdb) next
122     printf("%p\n",function);
(gdb) next
0xf7fbd000
123     int result = function();
(gdb) next
0xf7fbd000 in ?? ()
(gdb) next
Cannot find bounds of current function
```

I am unable to understand what is happening as it cannot find next line to run in the program.

Another attempt

```bash
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0xffffd1d4) at loader.c:136
136     if (argc != 2)
(gdb) next
143     load_and_run_elf((argv));
(gdb) next
file name : ./sum
fd : 3
reached line 65
reached line 69
0xf7fbd000

Breakpoint 2, load_and_run_elf (exe=0xffffd1d4) at loader.c:123
123     int result = function();
(gdb) step

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xf7fbd01c in ?? ()
(gdb) step
```

Comment: What's `check_elf_header` and `check_elf_class`?

Comment: @Armali this is used to check if it is elf file by checking magic number and check_elf_class is used to check byte format and version and many other things(basically it won't give problems if I have given elf file as command line parameter)

Answer (score 0):

The simple loader is a bit too simple insofar as it only allocates memory for the `.text` section, but not for `.bss` where the variables `A` and `sum` are placed; using them overwrites something (in my try the GOT, causing the print call to crash).

Comment: What is GOT and what does it do ?

Comment: How can I load every loadable segment into memory ? I tried to do it by making an array of void pointers but still it there is no change .

Comment: [Global Offset Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Offset_Table) - but that's not really important, something else may be overwritten in your case. - I can't say much about how you can _load every loadable segment into memory_ since I don't see your try _by making an array of void pointers_; regarding the `.bss`, one doesn't actually load it, its content is not stored in the file, but rather its memory just to be filled with zeros.

Comment: I solved it by loading segments in memory by handling segmentation faults